# HQL - two same queries - difference in object types

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, iteration

Why I have to use `Object[]` to print the list if I select specific columns:

```
Session session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory().openSession();
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>(); /* Object[] */

Query criteria = session.createQuery(
  "select test.col1, test.col2, test.col3
  "from Test test " +
  "group by test.col1, test.col2, test.col3");

list = criteria.list();

for (Object[] item : list)
{
  System.out.println(item[1] + ", " + item[2] + ", " + item[3]); 
}
```

And why is it possible to iterate the same select (select * -- not the specific columns) using original Test object?

```
List<Test> list = new ArrayList<Test>(); /* Test */
Query criteria = session.createQuery(
  "from Test test " +
  "group by test.col1, test.col2, test.col3");

list = criteria.list();

for (Test item : list)
{
  System.out.println(item.getCol1 + ", " + item.getCol2 + ", " + item.getCol3); 
}
```

Is it possible to "convert" `Object[]` to `Test` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach; first create a *constructor* in your `Test` class:

```
public Test(Col1Type col1, Col2Type2 col2, Col3Type col3) {
  this.col1 = col1;
  this.col2 = col2;
  this.col3 = col3;
}
```

Now in the query, you can say:

```
select new Test(t.col1, t.col2, t.col3) 
from Test t
```

This will give Hibernate a so-called row-mapper constructor out of which it can construct the objects of `Test`. Then you will have a `List<Test>` from `query.list()`. This approach has a catch that you should provide different constructors beside the *default* one for different possible queries.

Answer (score 1):

in your first query , you return a row (like a list) , consisting of several attributes of a "test" object that you have selected.
it is not "test" object , so you cannot iterate such way.

in your second query , you return the "test" object : a list of "Test" objects , so you can iterate as "test" object.